# Feasibility of linear inequalities with binary variables

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, decision-problem, integer-programming

I have a system of linear inequalities of the form $A^t x \leq b$, where each of the $x_i$'s is a binary variable in $\{0, 1\}$. Are there any known fast and practical algorithms that can find a feasible solution or prove that the system has no solutions?

I need this to generate an initial solution to the heterogenuous fleet VRP where the number of unknowns is ~ 10s of millions in each instance.

Comment: I guess you mean 'binary' variable. This comes under the scope of integer linear programming, which is unfortunately an NP-Hard problem.

Comment: Just to clarify on that: not only solving ILP for optimality is NP hard but also to find a feasible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an off-the-shelf integer linear programming solver.  That's exactly what they are designed to do.  The problem is NP-hard in general, so there are no guarantees -- there are certainly some problems that no existing solver can solve in any reasonable amount of time -- but you might get lucky.

Checking whether a feasible solution exists is also NP-complete, and it is (asymptotically, in general) about as hard as finding a feasible solution if one exists.